# Find shadow's height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

Just starting to learn physics. Now reading about constant motion and after this paragraph
I have a task:

Boy with growth of 1.5 m runs at a speed of 3 m / s in a straight line, passing under a street lamp, hanging at a height of 3 m. Show that the shadow of his head moves uniformly, and find the speed of the movement.

How can I know the height of his shadow to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Useful information:** Light travels in straight lines.

At a distance $d$ between the boy and the point on the ground directly beneath the light, at what distance will the top of the shadow be cast on the ground? Well, draw this scenario on paper and draw a straight line from the light, just touching the top of the boy and see where it hits the ground. Simple geometry tells us that this occurs at $2d$. Now we have a formula for the position of the top of the head (denoted by $h$) of the shadow as a function of distance of the boy from the light:
$$h=2d$$
You should now be able to see how to calculate the speed. I hope this helped.